# Striping text in scrappy

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, data-mining

I'm trying to run spyder to extract real estate advertisements informaiton.

My code:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import RealestateItem


class AddSpider (scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Add'
    start_urls = ['https://www.exampleurl.com/2-bedroom-apartment-downtown-4154251/']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = RealestateItem()

        whole_page = response.css('body')

        for item in whole_page:

            Title = response.css(".obj-header-text::text").extract()
            items['Title'] = Title
            yield items
```

After running in console:

```
scrapy crawl Add -o Data.csv
```

In .csv file I get

```
['\n            2-bedroom-apartment         ']
```

Tried adding strip method to function:

```
Title = response.css(".obj-header-text::text").extract().strip()
```

But scrapy returns:

```
Title = response.css(".obj-header-text::text").extract().strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Is there are some easy way to make scrapy return into .csv file just:

```
2-bedroom-apartment
```

Answer (score 1):

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

You get this error because `.extract()` returns a list, and `.strip()` is a method of string.

---

If that selector always returns ONE item, you could replace it with `.get()` [*or `extract_first()`*] instead of `.extract()`, this will return a string of the first item, instead of a list. Read more [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#id1).

If you need it to return a list, you can loop through the list, calling strip in each item like:

```
title = response.css(".obj-header-text::text").extract()
title = [item.strip() for item in title]
```

---

You can also use an XPath selector, instead of a CSS selector, that way you can use normalize-space to strip [whitespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space).

```
title = response.xpath('normalize-space(.//*[@class="obj-header-text"]/text())').extract()
```

*This XPath may need some adjustment, as you didn't post the source I couldn't check it*

Comment: Thank you, changing from .extract() to .get().strip() solved the issue

Comment: Happy to hear. Since the issue is resolved, please accept my answer by clicking the checkmark.